# how to make an animated custom dropdown menu

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

So here's my vision, I want my options to all be stacked at first, but then when the user clicks on a button, the container expands from top to bottom, and my options start appearing.
Here I attempted to make my idea clear

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [dropdown_button2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) plugin here is the example

```
String selectedValue;
List<String> items = [
  'Item1',
  'Item2',
  'Item3',
  'Item4',
];

DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
  child: DropdownButton2(
    hint: Text(
      'Select Item',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
    items: items
        .map((item) =>
        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: item,
          child: Text(
            item,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
          ),
        )
    ).toList(),
    value: selectedValue,
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        selectedValue = value as String;
      });
    },
    buttonHeight: 40,
    buttonWidth: 140,
    itemHeight: 40,
  ),
),
```